# How do I split every data or string that has a space on it using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I wrote a query which is this:

```
SELECT mrt_name as MRT ,
operation_alpha_numeric_codes as Original,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes,' ', 1) as First_code,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes,' ', -1) as Second_Code,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes,' ', -2) as Third_Code 
FROM scraping.xp_pn_mrt;
```

I got result like this

[image]

As you can see the `second_code` copies the value of the `original` or the `first_code` if the value doesn't have a corresponding space or data. Also, the `third` code gets the `second_code` in the records that have a third code in them. How do I prevent the data being copied or set it to blank when the code doesn't have a corresponding value in it and how can I achieve getting the third code without copying the second one? Can someone help me with my query and what's wrong with it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: its `Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.16-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64), source revision 0789a1a18f0e780c0412667e7b6e0a9970aa6905` @Nick

Comment: Please provide sample structure and data in a script or fiddle form, not as a picture.

Comment: I dont know how to add or use fiddle @Akina

Comment: *I dont know how to add or use fiddle* [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1d02e6824235081d14328c02ee34af07) (last editions not shown).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using MariaDB, you can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/) to extract the parts of the code that you want:

```
SELECT 
  operation_alpha_numeric_codes as Original,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(operation_alpha_numeric_codes, '^([^ ]+)(?: ([^ ]+))?(?: ([^ ]+))?$', '\\1') as First_code,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(operation_alpha_numeric_codes, '^([^ ]+)(?: ([^ ]+))?(?: ([^ ]+))?$', '\\2') as Second_code,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(operation_alpha_numeric_codes, '^([^ ]+)(?: ([^ ]+))?(?: ([^ ]+))?$', '\\3') as Third_code
FROM data
```

Output for (part of) your sample data

```
Original        First_code  Second_code     Third_code
NS23            NS23        
NS24 NE6 CC1    NS24        NE6             CC1
NS25 EW13       NS25        EW13
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d9db39ab38a2569046147894f8ffa12b)

Here's a version that will also work on MySQL 5.7, using `RLIKE` to check if the input matches given patterns:

```
SELECT 
  operation_alpha_numeric_codes as Original,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes, ' ', 1) AS First_code,
  CASE WHEN operation_alpha_numeric_codes RLIKE '^([^ ]+)$' THEN ''
       WHEN operation_alpha_numeric_codes RLIKE '^([^ ]+)( ([^ ]+))?$' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes, ' ', -1)
       ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes, ' ', 2), ' ', -1)
  END AS Second_code,
  CASE WHEN operation_alpha_numeric_codes RLIKE '^([^ ]+)( ([^ ]+)){2}$' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes, ' ', -1)
       ELSE ''
  END AS Third_code
FROM data
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=600e7ee2e0e4ddb6bf57255ec58b5ff8)

Comment: why does it has a error like this sir `REGEXP_REPLACE  does not exist`?

Comment: @Vince if you're using MariaDB > 10.0.5 it should definitely exist, and according to your version you are using 10.3.16

Comment: ya im using a later version of it but still not accepting `regexp` func. what seems the problem for this?

Comment: I tried `select version();` in my Workbench remote and it results `'5.7.22-log'
` but in my xampp local its `10.3.16-MariaDB`

Comment: So you are running a different version on your remote - that is MySQL, not MariaDB. Any chance you can upgrade (either to MySQL 8 or MariaDB)?

Comment: yah. Im using mysql in my remote but in my local is mariaDB. I dont have credentials to upgrade mysql in remote.

Comment: @Vince I added a MySQL version of the query

Comment: then why it does not work? I dont really know the problems of your queries all. seems correct but if i try in my remote its not getting the correct one

Comment: the latest answer you give i try it in aand its only getting the first code

Comment: @Vince I've edited the query. It works fine in MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 on dbfiddle

Comment: My values got two spaces in between them.

Comment: @Vince try this for multiple spaces: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7f80d4aab431e674aeb931588b206c80

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. Can you explain what you did?

Comment: @Vince I changed the regexes to match more than one space, and added a replace to convert the multiple spaces to 1 where it was needed for second_code

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT 
   mrt_name as MRT ,
   operation_alpha_numeric_codes as Original,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes , ' ', 1), ' ', -1) AS First_code,
   If(  length(operation_alpha_numeric_codes ) - length(replace(operation_alpha_numeric_codes , ' ', ''))>=1,  
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes , ' ', 2), ' ', -1) , '') 
           as Second_code,
   If(  length(operation_alpha_numeric_codes ) - length(replace(operation_alpha_numeric_codes , ' ', ''))>=2,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes , ' ', 3), ' ', -1), '') 
           AS Third_code
FROM scraping.xp_pn_mrt;
```

[EDIT]

For double spaces between each value, This will work:

```
SELECT 
   mrt_name as MRT ,
   operation_alpha_numeric_codes as Original,
If(  length(operation_alpha_numeric_codes ) - length(replace(operation_alpha_numeric_codes , ' ', ''))>=2,  
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes , ' ', 3), ' ', -1) , '') 
           as Second_code,
   If(  length(operation_alpha_numeric_codes ) - length(replace(operation_alpha_numeric_codes , ' ', ''))>=4,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes , ' ', 3), ' ', -1), '') AS Third_code
FROM scraping.xp_pn_mrt;
```

Comment: I tried it has a problem, if the value has a second index, the second index becomes null and the value goes to the third and vise versa

Comment: Sorry, I have made the edits to consider that case.

Comment: it got worse sir. the second goes to the third and the second is not detected.

Comment: Please try again. I made a mistake while typing it in, `>1` should be replaced with `>=1`. I have reedited it.

Comment: its the same sir. What seems to be the problem for this?

Comment: It's actually working on my fiddle. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1db5538bf30e4b190f1f2f1af7a23693)

Comment: @Vince [SqlFIddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f46260/1) It works here too... :( Sorry if it didn't help.

Comment: its okay. i upvoted your answer dont worry bro. thanks for the effort

Comment: @Vince I think there may be a trailing space for your entry in `operation_alpha_numeric_codes`.  I edited `=2` to `>=2` for that case, for the final time. Please try!

Answer (score 1):

I have used `CASE WHEN` clause with `LENGTH` function.
I used LENGTH to calculate number of occurences of your separator ' ' in the string. CASE WHEN it is ONE occurances then there are TWO "results". CASE WHEN it is TWO occurances then there are THREE "results".

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8cb298ef53915beb07516ab22c6d9ebb) that will show the correct results for your two problematic data.

```
SELECT mrt_name as MRT 
   , operation_alpha_numeric_codes as Original
   , SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes,' ', 1) as First_code
   , CASE WHEN LENGTH(operation_alpha_numeric_codes) - LENGTH(REPLACE(operation_alpha_numeric_codes, ' ', '')) = 1 
          THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes,' ', -1)
          WHEN LENGTH(operation_alpha_numeric_codes) - LENGTH(REPLACE(operation_alpha_numeric_codes, ' ', '')) = 2
          THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes,' ', 2), ' ', -1)
          ELSE NULL
     END Second_Code
   , CASE WHEN LENGTH(operation_alpha_numeric_codes) - LENGTH(REPLACE(operation_alpha_numeric_codes, ' ', '')) = 2 
          THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(operation_alpha_numeric_codes,' ', -2), ' ', -1)
          ELSE NULL
     END Third_Code
FROM scraping.xp_pn_mrt;
```

Comment: No errors in the query but, if i only have two codes. the second one goes to the third leaving the second column null. And if I have three codes, the second and third returns null

Comment: You are fast :) sorry , still edditing answer... Try now

Comment: Its the same sir. I dont know what seems to be the problem of this

Comment: Please refresh the page and try again. Have you see the demo ? Refres the page = maybe you are copy - paste the old code that I have corrected...

Comment: im using mysql 5.7. Yes i have seen the demo. did you try putting 3 codes in the data?

Comment: @Vince I have founded the solution and updated my answer.

Comment: @Vince I have also updated the DEMO with 3 examples and for the version you have.

Comment: it gets me a row like this `NS1  EW24 operation_alpha_numeric_codes  NULL         NULL`

Comment: :) sorry, I have forgot to remove the ' '. Did it now.

Comment: my God I dont even know whats the problem, The latest answer you give is the same. the second moves to the third and when i got 3 codes the 2nd and 3rd becomes null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205986/discussion-between-vboka-and-vince).